# Scaling y-axis in Librosa spectrogram

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I'm displaying the results of a CQT using `librosa.display.specshow` as follows:

```py
sr = 22050 
cqt = librosa.cqt(y, sr = sr)
librosa.display.specshow(abs(cqt), sr = sr, x_axis = "time", y_axis = "cqt_note")
```

with the following output:

[image: Output]

However, I would like the y-axis to only range from C4 to C5 and preferably show the notes in within that octave so it's easier to see what notes are being played. After looking at the **[documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/0.9.1/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html)**, I tried using:

```py
librosa.display.specshow(abs(cqt), sr = sr, x_axis = "time", y_axis = "cqt_note", fmin = librosa.note_to_hz("C4"), fmax = librosa.note_to_hz("C5"))
```

But that prints the following warning:

> UserWarning: Frequency axis exceeds Nyquist. Did you remember to set all spectrogram parameters in specshow?

and only shows a y-shifted plot that starts at C4 and goes to C11 (with the same scaling as before):

[image: Second output]

Is it possible to scale the y-axis and if it is how can I?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this could be fixed by adding `bins_per_octave` as an argument, i.e.:

```py
librosa.display.specshow(abs(cqt), sr = sr, 
x_axis = "time", y_axis = "cqt_note", 
fmin = librosa.note_to_hz("C4"), 
fmax = librosa.note_to_hz("C5"), 
bins_per_octave = 80)
```

Output:

[image: Output]